# MySQL query - Use SELECT inside an UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, offset

I'm trying to select a particular row in a database using SELECT and OFFSET. The result I get is logical and I do get the desired row I want. But then I need to UPDATE that same specific row so I do something like that:

```
UPDATE table 
SET value=1 
WHERE value IN (SELECT * FROM(
SELECT value FROM table WHERE some criteria LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) temp_tab);
```

Now what I expect from this code is to UPDATE the selected row ONLY. Instead it Updates ALL rows in the datatable and sets their value to 1.

When I use only:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT value FROM table WHERE some criteria LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) temp_tab
```

I get only 1 row as the output. (LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2 makes sure I do get the 1 row and it's the 2nd available) I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong or how I am supposed to achieve this.

Note: I do have to use SELECT and not some other method using unique ID of the row or something similar.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `value`. Use something unique like `id`. `...WHERE id IN ...`

Comment: @juergend d In my case I need to use a SELECT statement to specify that specific row and the way I select it is by using OFFSET X (because the criterias in the WHERE cause make sure I get the rows I want but then I need only 1 from them) and what I expect is that value is set to 1 only on that selected row where I did WHERE value IN (selection) but instead the SET is applied to all rows in the table, not only the selection. Sorry for my poor English in case you're having problems understanding me.

Comment: I get it. But why use  `SELECT value from your_table`? Do `UPDATE table 
SET value=1 
WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE some criteria LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) temp_tab)` instead.

Comment: @juergend id? I do not have an id. In fact my table does not include a column that lets each row has its own unique "id" or something. They are all really similar and I just want to pick ANY from it via OFFSET and modify it. I'm not really advanced into sql (if at all) but the way I get it is that WHERE value IN(selection) specifies which "value" should be modified in the SET value=1 section. I'm pretty sure I have a misunderstanding of how it works or something...

Comment: @Chogart: ouch, you should really always have a way to uniquely identify rows. I advise a simple integer id column. In fact, under the hood MySQL already created an id column for you, so you'd not saving any space by omitting an id field, and you'd not gaining any performance. You''ve just created a table that's hard to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` you need to use `ORDER BY` as well.  Otherwise the row you get is indeterminate.

One method uses `LIMIT` within the `UPDATE` itself.  However, `UPDATE` doesn't allow `OFFSET`.  So:

```
UPDATE table 
    SET value = 1 
    WHERE some criteria
    ORDER BY ??
    LIMIT 1;
```

The best method would use a unique id.  You can do this with the double subquery approach:

```
UPDATE table 
    SET value = 1 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                 FROM (SELECT id
                       FROM table
                       WHERE some criteria
                       ORDER BY ??
                       LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
                      ) t
                );
```

If you don't have a single unique id, you can use multiple columns that uniquely define a single row.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you that's exactly what solved my problem. Well, not exactly... but it gave me a better idea of how things work so I managed to achieve my goal. Thank you once again!